# How does lighttpd/nginx determine filetype of a file? (which method?)

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, lighttpd, mime-type

I want to configure my lighttpd to serve some static files, with compression capability. The files are plain text but they have `.bin` extension. I have these lines in my lighttpd configuration:

```
compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ("text/plain", "text/html", "application/x-javascript", "text/css")
```

And it works for css and js files, but not for the `.bin` files.

Here is the output of `file -i` for one fo those `.bin` files:

```
8_1.bin: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

**How can I determine the file type of this file the same way lighttpd does it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/mime.types` by default defines .bin files as a "**application/octet-stream**", so please try add "application/octet-stream" to your compress.filetype table

Comment: that is a stupid idea. map ".bin" to a better mime type (for example the output that `file` gave you). you don't want to compress all application/octet-stream files. See http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Mimetype_assignDetails

Comment: I think that mapping .bin to text/plain is a terrible idea... but of course you have right to present your point of view ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You should have a MIME file containing a dictionary related to all filetypes.

Comment: hum... why the hell is someone downgrading this answer? The upper one, which has been posted at the same time contain the same answer!!